# Granger causality testing with rq() quantile regression

Tags: time-series, quantile-regression, granger-causality

I am trying to test for Granger causality in my quantile regression. I have x (=position data) and y (=price data) in a dataframe called `dat` and then employ quantile regression with `rq()`:

```
qs <- 1:9/10
rqfit <- rq(price ~ position, tau=qs, data=dat)
coef(rqfit)
ggplot(dat, aes(position,price))+geom_point()+geom_quantile(quantiles=qs)
```

How can I test for Granger causality afterwards, since `causality()` in the vars package only works for `varest objects` and `grangertest()` only works for `lm class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your quantile regression, include lags of price and lags of position as regressors. Then use an $F$ or $\chi^2$ test of the hypothesis that coefficients on lags of position are all equal to zero. This will be a test of the null hypothesis that position does not Granger-cause price.

This assumes both the price and the position time series are stationary. For integrated and cointegrated series, a more involved procedure would be needed.

Here is sample R code for running the model with 3 lags for the median (quantile level `tau=0.5`):

```r
library(quantreg)
tau=0.5
lag=3
set.seed(1); price   =runif(100)
set.seed(2); position=runif(100)
prices   =embed(price   ,lag+1)
positions=embed(position,lag+1)
model=rq(prices[,1]~prices[,2:(lag+1)]+positions[,2:(lag+1)],tau=tau)
```

Comment: Thank you @Richard! How do I include the lags? And which function do you recommend for the F test?

Comment: @Anna, you have to create lags first, e.g. using the function `embed`, and then add them into the model. See my edit. I do not remember how to implement an F test, but it cannot be too difficult. Check out the `quantreg` package and Section 6 of the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/vignettes/rq.pdf). It talks about testing there.

Comment: I did the following: model1 <- rq(prices[,1]~prices[,2:(lag+1)]+positions[,2:(lag+1)])
model2 <- rq(prices[,1]~prices[,2:(lag+1)])
anova <- anova(model1, model2).Does this count as an Granger causality test? And does a p-value<0.05 now say that there is Granger causality?

Comment: But now I see: where is the definition of quantiles tau=... in your regression rq()?

Comment: I just added the quantiles: model1 <- rq(prices[,1]~prices[,2:(lag+1)]+positions[,2:(lag+1)], tau=qs)
model2 <- rq(prices[,1]~prices[,2:(lag+1)], tau=qs)
anova <- anova(model1, model2)

Comment: @Anna, I have updated the answer again to include the quantiles of interest. I am not sure however whether `anova` does what you think it does. It may or it may not, I would need to read the documentation of `anova`. Since I am pretty busy with work at the moment, I think it is reasonable that you read it yourself.